# Yii2 - Upgrade Bootstrap 3 to 4

Tags: bootstrap-4, yii2

i'm trying upgrade bootstrap from version 3 to 4, with [this](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4) official extension and now works partial. for example i use in my project  a widgets from 2amigos and i think is dependent from bootstrap 3. in the pages where i have a widget from 2 amigos the bootstrap3 is called always and deconfigured my layout (constructed in BS4) it's possible remove completely bootstrap 3 or other solution for not call BS3 anymore?

other thing i see is the module Gii also layout desconfugured.

installation

```
php composer.phar require --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4
```

class AppAsset

```
public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap4\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
```

and i rename all from `yii\bootstrap` to `yii\bootstrap4`

i also try remove `yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "~2.0.0"` from `composer.json` but not work, the results is same.

Comment: did you removed the previous entry of the `"yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap"` from your `composer.json` before installing the `yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4` , its pretty straight forward remove the previous version run `composer update` then add the new one `yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4:"~1.0.0"` and then run `composer update` after that change your assets class depends array and that is it. i just configured before adding this message

Comment: Did you tried just to remove this problematic widget which uses BS3? Running `composer why yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap` may find dependencies that use BS3.

Comment: i did everything as @MuhammadOmerAslam said and i still removed the folder in `vendor>yiisoft>yii2-bootstrap` manually, it worked fine thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to remove the previous entry of the `"yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap"` from your `composer.json` before installing the `yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4`, its pretty straight forward

- remove the previous version
- run `composer update`
- add the new one `yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4:"~1.0.0"`
- run composer update

after that change the namespace to the new class in your assets class `$depends` array and that is it.

You can also remove the associated folder manually or delete the whole vendor folder, and then run `composer update`

Comment: as I said, I did all this and removed  `vendor>yiisoft>yii2-bootstrap` folder manually, it worked fine thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you install yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap4 without deleting yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap, so you need only change all uses in views files like this:

use yii\bootstrap\Nav => use yii\bootstrap4\Nav

use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm => use yii\bootstrap4\ActiveForm

and etc.

This change will call bootstrap 4 in view files.

Note: common\widgets\Alert.php use bootstrap 3.4 by default, you need replace it to bootstrap4 as shown upper. It prevents to call 2 bootstrap versions (3.4 and 4.x), when you need show default Alerts.